# What's the correct way to intercept keyboard events in html with an SVG document?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom-events

I have a html document whose relevant portion for this question is as follows:

```
<body onload='main()'>

<object id='svg' type="image/svg+xml" data="b.svg"></object>

</body>
```

The function main (`onload = ..`) is used to install an event handler for the *keydown* event:

```
function main() {

  document.addEventListener('keydown', 
       function(ev) { 
         console.log('DOC keydown, ev.keyCode = ' + ev.keyCode); 
        },
       false);
}
```

This works as intended *until* I click into the area occupied by `b.svg`. Afterwards, the keyboard events seem somehow to be processed through/within the SVG document and they don't make it to the `document` object's event handler.

I can now add *another* event listener on the SVG element itself:

```
  var svg=document.getElementById('svg');
  var svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;

  svgDoc.addEventListener('keydown', 
       function(ev) { 
         console.log('SVG keydown, ev.keyCode = ' + ev.keyCode); 
        },
       false);
```

Which again does work as intended.

Yet, I feel this is a bit clumsy and inelegant. If possible, I'd like to have only one event listener.

So, is this the correct way to handle keyboard events in a html page with an SVG drawing, or are there better alternatives?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the svg to process events add pointer-events="none" to its root element.